# Truffle Console - call function with struct params

Tags: truffle

I have the below test contract. is it possible through the truffle console to call the function "testStruct" that takes as an argument a struct?

```
contract TestContract{

    struct TestStructArgs { 
        string title;
        string details;
    }
   
    function testStruct(TestStructArgs memory _params) external{      
    
    }
    function testStruct2(string  memory _params) external{      
    
    }
}
```

Its being defined as

> 'testStruct((string,string))': [Function: bound _createTxObject]

### EDIT:

Im using Visual Studio Code with the "Truffle for VS Code extension" version 2.7.1
Im also using Ganache to deploy the contract into a local blockchain

Commands i execute on the VS console:

```
    truffle console --network ganache
    migrate --reset
    let contract = TestContract.deployed();
    const object = {title: "Hello", details: "Hey"};
    await contract.testStruct(object);
```

after this i get

```
    Uncaught TypeError: contract.testStruct is not a function
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:26
```

but all is ok if i execute

```
await contract.testStruct2("test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object with the same structure as the struct in solidity.

Here,

```
const object = {title: "Hello", details: "Hey"};
await contract.testStruct(object);
```

Then in the solidity function, you can have the same parameters as the struct.

```
mapping(address => TestStructArgs) mapp;
function testStruct(TestStructArgs memory _params) external{
    mapp[msg.sender].title = _params.title;
    mapp[msg.sender].details = _params.details;        
}
```

It's as simple as that.
All this is possible easily since solidity resembles javascript to quite an extent.
I hope this answers your query.

Comment: I did try this but i'm getting "instance.testStruct is not a function"

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: thanks , i just updated my post with more details

Comment: You got to await till the contract gets deployed.
let contract = await TestContract.deployed();
This should do it.

Comment: thank you , that did it!